Statistical techniques to compare leaves position across ordered trees
I want to tackle this problem.
Suppose I have a set of entries that can produce multiple ordered trees based on some statistical methodology. The entries are always the same, but the tree structure changes based on some measurements. So, we get a set of trees, all with the same leaves, but different structures. Now, between two measurements we might observe some leaves moving: one leaf might just move slightly (change position near the end of the branches), and that could be just due to noise (low significance). Otherwise, a leave might belong to a completely different branch, say with a difference at the first or second split after the root (high significance).
I would like to use a statistical method to quantify the significance of "differential positioning" in the tree. Please note that I'm interested in assigning significance to each leaf, not to the clustering result or the difference between the trees themselves.
I also can build a NULL model with a bunch of trees that will show some variability due to injected noise.
Are there any available methodologies to do this?
